# GRUB > unknown filesystem

Tags: grub2, boot-loader

I just created a USB bootable for ubuntu (but also tried other distrib) but I did not succeed to go on it since GRUB display this:

```
error: unknow filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0)(hd1)
```

I have a XPS 13 (9360) and I don't know how to fix this problem... I tried some solutions proposed over the web but it did not works for me.

Resume: I put ubuntu (version 17.04) on an USB flash drive for boot on it and install ubuntu but I can't since GRUB (from the USB flash drive) give me this error. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue#answer-166338) for example but it failed every time after insmod normal.

PS: I switch the SATA mode from RAID to AHCI but I don't think it's related since booting on the USB flash drive should not depend on my SSD.

Comment: Did you try the steps described at https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem ?

Comment: Yes, it did not work for me. I have not the same output, ex I see `(hd0)(hd1)` and not `(hdX,Y)`

Comment: That seems to show that you didn't partition the drive, which apparently doesn't prevent `grub` from loading, therefore it could be bootable.

Comment: Yes. But each time I try `insmod ...` I get `error: no such partition`

Comment: I think this can be solved but your best bet is probably to partition the drive properly and reinstall.

Comment: `(hdX,Y)` means "where X is the drive and Y is the partition on the drive where the root partition of the system is". So, if the root partition is on `sda5`, you'd enter `(hd0,5)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To bypass this problem, here it's what I did:

- use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)
- choose "MBR partition schema for UEFI"
- write in DD image mode

Comment: This does not answer your own question.  It shows one of multiple ways to properly write a bootable USB drive but it doesn't show how to fix your issue.  This makes the question completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use [Boot Repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) to Repair you grub .and when you  Log On the Boot Repair system you may use fdisk -l to lookup you Hard Disk . and with worst-case is mean you must backup your file and reinstall the system

Comment: I don't have grub installed yet... It's the one from my USB flash drive for run the live CD.

Comment: so i think you may reform ubnutu  live cd， this maybe about ubuntu ISO md5 , redownload and  check the iso md5 right